# Can I create a entity mapping to table which has a name from specific property of the entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

For example, I have an entity below.

```java
@Entity
public class Indexer 
    @NotNull @Id
    private long id;

    @Column 
    private string volumeKey;
}
```

I want to create a table with a ‘volumeKey’ property in this entity.

For example, A indexer has a ‘X12372’ as a `volumeKey` of property. I want this entity to be mapped to ‘INDEXER_X12372’.

And I tried to create custom `NamingStrategy` class for Indexer. And I can’t get an entity to be mapped in this class for making a table of name from.

Comment: I guess `@Column(name="INDEXER_X12372")` is not what you want?
In which way does creating a `NamingStrategy` not work?

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. You want the table to be used to be determined by a value of a property, right?

Comment: You can do that with "partitioning" if your database supports this. See for example https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b32024/partition.htm

Comment: Yeah. That’s what I mean. The entity should determine a table to use from a property of it. Thanks your comment. I will read it later. I am not sure that is suitable solution for me yet. I prefer to get a solution in spring JPA.

Answer (score 0):

You want the table to be used to be determined by a value of a property.

This is not possible with JPA or Spring Data JPA.
But some (many?) databases can do this transparently with partitioned tables. 
See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b32024/partition.htm for Oracle documentation as an example.

It should be easy enough to find a similar document for the database you use.